# XSLT Date Comparisons

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="date1" select="2011-10-05"/>
<xsl:variable name="date2" select="2011-10-05"/>
<xsl:variable name="date3" select="2011-10-06"/>

<xsl:if test="$date2 = $date1 or $date2 &lt; $date1">
  ..do something
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="$date3 = $date1 or $date3 &gt; $date1">
 .. do something
</xsl:if>
```

Both should evaluate true, but the second if doesn't. For the life of me I can't comprehended why!

In the actual transform the dates themselves are being drawn from an XML document but debugging through VS2010 i can see the values are as above.

Must be something fairly fundamental i'm doing wrong - any help would be brilliant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this in Oxygen/XML... `select="2011-10-05` is being interpreted as an arithmetic expression, giving the value 1996 (2011 minus 10 minus 5) and `"2011-10-06"` is intrepreted as 1995.

What you want is

```
<xsl:variable name="date1" select="'2011-10-05'"/>
<xsl:variable name="date2" select="'2011-10-05'"/>
<xsl:variable name="date3" select="'2011-10-06'"/>
```

Note the extra single quotes.

From the [XSLT 1.0 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#variables):

> If the variable-binding element has a select attribute, then the value
>   of the attribute must be an expression and the value of the variable
>   is the object that results from evaluating the expression.

Comment: Even better, declare the variables to be of type date. If you get into the habit of doing this, it's surprising how many silly mistakes like this lead to sensible error messages instead of confusing wrong output. `<xsl:variable name="d1" as="xs:date" select="xs:date('2011-10-05')"/>`

Comment: Agreed, of course, but since the OP didn't specify, and he mentioned Visual Studio, I was assuming XSLT 1.0.